# Customizing the number of cores within a tile in rocketchip

Tags: riscv, chisel, soc

I'm using RISC-V I would like to customize the number of cores in a tile.

Which chisel file should I modify?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using RocketChip generator?
If you want to create several cores, you can change the number of cores in "rocket-chip/src/main/scala/uncore/Builder.scala" NTiles param.
If you want to add it inside a Tile, maybe you should modify rocket.scala and tile.scala, but take into account that they will share the L1 cachés and that could create conflicts.

Comment: Thank you M. Ramos, I have succesfully built two cores in a same Tile by making changes in Configs.scala, tile.scala, Rocketchip.scala and rocket.scala. Now I'm looking for a way to identify outputs of each core and compare them. Regards